# How to increase mouse sensitivity beyond normal limit?

Tags: windows-xp, mouse

It's ***one*** faster.

My office PC (DELL) runs WinXP. It has an el-cheapo DELL laser mouse. I find that maximum mouse sensitivity in Control Panel is not fast enough for me.

Is there a way to take my sensitivity beyond the Control Panel limit?

**Can my mouse go to 11?**

Comment: I have not. Where and how do I do so?

Comment: Within a terminal. Check the manpage and see if it offers anything more than the Control Panel - it may not...

Comment: @trojanfoe He's running Windows XP, `x11` tag was wrong.

Comment: actually, it was a joke -- *goes to 11* and all that. But sorry if it caused confusion!

Comment: Oops :/  Sorry scratch that

Comment: you can try another mouse pad ,if you are using one ,look at the gaming ones ,they should improve your experience

Comment: +1 for SpinalTap Reference (This one goes to 11) :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure a software solution will be ideal (or even possible) here.

Are you averse to bringing your own mouse to work? Many gaming style mice have hardware DPI selectors, which let you switch on the fly from, say, 200 DPI (glacially slow) to 2000+ DPI (your cursor is now *on fire*).

Something like the Dell J660d mouse can be picked up for around $10

http://www.google.com/products/catalog?q=dell+J660D

and it has the requisite hardware switching of DPI:

> Adjustable DPI: 400, 800, 1200 or 1600 DPI with a Click of the Mouse.

Comment: I am not averse. I was just curious if there was a way to exceed the **steely grip of Control Panel** without using new hardware. You see the oppression inherent in the system!

Comment: +1 for flaming mouse cursors. I have yet to find a use for my G5's 2000dpi setting, though!

Answer (score 2):

Is "Enhance pointer precision" checked?

This enables mouse acceleration - the pointer will move faster at higher mouse-speeds.

Comment: But it won't have linear response, so you cannot twitch-click accurately

Answer (score 2):

It's late answer but I managed to do it in registry.

Go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Mouse`.

Assuming that your mouse is very slow, then you need to change value of `MouseSpeed` to `2`(to quadruple the normal mouse speed).
Then set the values of `MouseThreshold1` to `1` and `MouseThreshold2` to `2`.

When I tried to set the Thresholds to 0 it was like I have unchecked the `Enhance pointer precision` so I set it back at 1 and 2. (I'm running Windows 7)

Answer (score 0):

Open 'Registry Editor' in your machine.

```
Run > regedit
```

Look for the following key

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Mouse\MouseSensitivity
```

Change the 'Value data:' to the sensitivity you require. Restart your machine.

Comment: hmm. currently set to 20. Assuming that Min=0 and Max=20 on the CPanel scale, I'm gonna go with 25 and reboot... back in a minute.

Comment: This didn't work, surprisingly. Here's what happened: setting to 25, after reboot the mouse was much slower. Inspecting CP showed sensitivity set to middle! Changing the slider I confirmed that the min is 1 and the max 20. I used RegEdit to set the value to 30 and rebooted again. And once again the mouse was automatically set at middle sensitivity. It seems anything above 20 is considered spurious and is overridden by Windows to be "medium"!

Comment: @Andrew Heath I thought you wanted to push the mouse sensitivity above 11. At least thats what the question made it sound like.

Comment: also good info http://support.microsoft.com/kb/q149228/

Comment: @Thomas; "goes to 11" is a phrase used to mean "Pushed beyond what it can normally do". It was popularised by the film `This is Spinal Tap`, in which they had an amplifier go up to 11 for extra extreme-ness (Rather than just keeping 1-10 and having 10 go higher), and has become fairly popular for "taking something to the extreme".

Comment: @Phoshi Good to know :)

Answer (score 0):

I use a Steelseries Rival optical mouse, you can go on their website and download an engine that let's you increase the sensitivity beyond 'control panel' as well as make some other adjustments, etc.

My suggestion would be to look up the model of your mouse and search for
 software that can add to or over ride control panel limits.