# Set mouse sensitivity beyond maximum

Tags: windows-7, mouse

There are [many](https://superuser.com/a/286115/228377), [many](https://superuser.com/a/469051/228377) duplicates to this.

I do not wish to buy a mouse with higher DPI. If setting my mouse speed higher degrades the performance, that would still be fine.

I have tried setting `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Mouse\MouseSpeed\MouseSpeed` to `2` and restarting. All it did was enable pointer precision, which I want to keep disabled.

How can I double or even triple my current mouse speed which is set at eleven?

[image]

Comment: The problem with increasing your pointer speed is that at some point you will start skipping pixels which makes precisely clicking on things extremely annoying. In fact, I'd venture a guess that right now you're cursor actually skips pixels with it set to max. Pushing to double or triple the maximum Windows mouse speed will cause the cursor to skip over checkboxes, buttons, ect *completely*, making the computer rather un-usable. A higher DPI mouse is really the only option to maintain accuracy with a fast cursor speed.

Comment: I'm okay with the mouse skipping pixels, as I'm using this for gaming. Accuracy is nice, but speed is what I'm going for.

Comment: Did you change all 3 reg entries as indicated in the [refrence](http://superuser.com/questions/469044/how-to-increase-mouse-sensitivity-beyond-limits-in-windows-regedit/469051#469051) you gave?

Comment: I believe setting MouseSpeed deals with acceleration. I have pointer precision disabled, so I have only one threshold.

Comment: Skipping pixels is VERY bad for gaming. Check game options for a sensitivity slider. Higher DPI mouse is still your best option, you can get a high DPI mouse very cheaply.

Comment: "I'm okay with the mouse skipping pixels, as I'm using this for gaming." Really, then you will also skip the enemy you want to shoot, buy a better mouse, they are quite cheap. I own a $6 dollar gaming mouse with dedicated DPI button and side buttons. Works great.

Answer (score 2):

Although I agree with the suggestions to buy a higher DPI mouse, there may be a way to set the speed higher.

Open the run prompt (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) and access regedit.

Find "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Mouse"

Set the values of MouseThreshold1 and MouseThreshold2 to zero.

Finally set MouseSpeed to 1 or 2 (1 Doubles mouse speed, 2 quadruples it).

Close all programs and restart.

Comment: Just to point it out, "MouseSpeed" is mouse acceleration, not a "make things faster" setting. It's more like a workaround to turn that on, although it is usually turned on by default.